# How far would I need to go back in time to find an isolated island on our earth?

Tags: geography, earth, exploration

If you want to tell a story of a lonely island on earth, isolated from the rest of the civilization, how many years do you have to go back to be realistic?

I think about a story about 350 people who survive a shipwreck. It is very important for the story that they have to stay on that island for the rest of their lives, because nobody will find them.

I do not know when some major trading routes where established between Europe and other continents. It is very important for the story that frequently used trade routes used by ships were either not existent or far away from the island.

@kingledion: Thanks for your answer. Do you think we have to go back that far. Would be for example 1710 not sufficient? I think it is easier for me to tell a story that is not that far back, because the life is a bit more similar than our live today.

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding *Wolfgang*! If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. Have fun!

Comment: Assuming that someone offers up an island with a relatively recent absence of human life, you will actually want to travel back further than the arrival of its first inhabitants.  To know how much further, we need to know how much time your story will cover...  months, years or generations?

Comment: New Zealand was first populated sometime in the 13th century; before that there were no people on the islands. Madagascar was first populated sometime during the 3rd and the 13th century; anyway, before the 13th century (opinions vary). The entire subsaharan Africa was functionally isolated from Eurasia and northern Africa up to the end of the antiquity, say 4th to 7th century, when the introduction of the camel (from Asia) made desert crossings practicable. The Americas were isolated from Afroeurasia up to the 15th century. Australia and Tasmania were isolated until the 18th century.

Comment: The Americas were never isolated from Eurasia since the time humans first entered the continents. Just as an example, the modern Canadian Inuit rose from the Thule culture, which began on both sides of the Bering Strait as the Old Bering Seas stage around 200 BCE and then migrated east, arriving in Greenland at about the same time as the Vikings, around 1000 CE. While there might not have been a lot of trade, it wouldn't surprise me if someday someone found a Roman coin in North America, having been passed along and making its way across.

Comment: You don't have to go back in time at all.  There's an island in the Indian Ocean where the natives kill anyone from outside who lands there.

Comment: How big your island needs to be? Would "Cast Away" type of island suffice?

Comment: Depending on how big you need your island, 0 seconds. We still haven't busted every place on Earth and even now there are times a tribe not known to the rest of the world is found. Otherwise going back to the 1400s Age of Exploration would feel good, but that's more opinion than fact.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about what you mean? 

Are you looking for an island isolated from the rest of the world with an indigenous population, or an uninhabited island? Both currently exist in the world today.

Comment: @AlexP Australia and Tasmania were settled fifty thousand years ago by what are now its indigenous inhabitants. Tasmania works fine before fifty thousand years. So does New Zealand and much of Polynesia.

Comment: @a4android: The question says "isolated", which is ambiguous. Tasmania was indeed settled in prehistory but was then isolated. New Zealand was settled by the Polynesians in the 13th century and had no human population before that.

Comment: @AlexP Definitely "isolated" is ambiguous. I'm not sure if Tasmania was isolated from mainland Australia, probably was as the Bass Strait is a formidable barrier for seafarers. That would be worth checking, even out of personal curiosity. Mine, that is. Sorry, thinking with my fingers. Also, the question is "isolated from the rest of civilization" which adds further ambiguity. Retires puzzled.

Comment: Why do you need to go back in time to find an isolated island? Why can't the marooned people stumble across an undiscovered island? This will be a work of fiction :)

Comment: @jamesqf I feel like that undermines the story plot point of "stay on the island for the rest of their lives" and replaces it with "killed and eaten by natives."

Comment: You aren't supposed to add further requirements to your question after it has been asked. The way to do that is to comment on my answer and ask me to expand or clarify.

Comment: ok, I understand.

Comment: @kingledion: Well, "killed and eaten by natives" just means "the rest of their lives" was rather short, no?  But I really don't think the question is answerable, because if you are in a period where ~350 people can be on a ship, there's going to be enough seagoing traffic that the survivors will eventually be discovered.  For instance the Bounty mutineers were deliberately trying to hide, but it only took about 18 years for the survivors to be found.

Comment: @jamesqf: Thank you for you historical input!

Comment: I think this needs to be farther back than other responses said or special circumstances. 350 people is quite a workforce, they should be able to build a boat that can at least get some of them of the island and organize a rescue expedition. Unless there are no materials to build one, or nobody has enough navigatory knowledge to figure out where they are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## 500 years

[Mauritius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mauritius) and [Reunion/Bourbon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A9union) are relatively large islands (about 2000 and 2500 km$^2$, respectively). They were isolated from people and evidently not visited until the Portuguese stopped by both in 1507. These islands were permanently occupied by the Dutch in 1598 (Mauritius) and the French in 1642 (Reunion). The Dutch attempts on Mauritius actually failed several times, and petered out for good in 1710, whereupon Mauritius was permanently colonized by the French in 1715.

Mauritius is of course famous as the home of the dodo, which did not long survive first contact with humans.

## 200 years?

The islands of the South Atlantic, in particular [Tristan da Cunha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tristan_da_Cunha) in the aptly named Inaccessible Isles are even less visited. They were also first visited around the same time period, in 1506, again by the Portuguese. But they were sighted, there is no record of a landing until 1643, by the Dutch. There are only four other records of a landing by the Dutch, who also were the first to add the islands to a map in 1658. The first official survey of the islands was in 1767 by the French, and the first settlers were American whalers in 1810.

However, there are a lot of downsides to these islands. Unlike Mauritus and Reunion, these islands have no mammals (not counting seals), reptiles, butterflies, or snails. Also important, these islands have no trees and no rivers, although it is super rainy. The record high on the islands is 24 C/75 F, and the record low is 4 C/40 F; it is pretty much 17 C / 64 F every day in the summer and 12 C / 54 F every day in the winter. It also rains at least 1/2 of the days, up to 5/6 days in the winter. The summer averages 5 hours of sunshine a day, down to 3 in the winter. All in all, not super hospitable.

Answer (score 3):

**Possibly about 1800, but more likely before the Age of Exploration**

All but one of the men who landed on [Pitcairn Island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitcairn_Islands) in 1790 died on the island before the next ship to actually send someone ashore found it, in 1808.  Three ships had passed within view without stopping or signalling in the interim.

So it's plausible for a larger group to have settled on a similarly remote, perhaps slightly larger, island at about that time; but to make it likeley that young adults in the party would be there for "the rest of their [lives]", there would have to be additional factors, like severe climate-change and wars at home, meaning civilization pulled back on general exploration.

And if you meant "rest of their [lives]" simply in terms of dying there, not living to a ripe old age, there are other comparable examples; for example, the first English colony at [Roanoke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roanoke_Colony), founded in 1585 and gone when the next ship arrived, five years later.

But even back in the 1500s, if a party shipwrecked somewhere, there was a good chance that someone else would come afterward (either looking for them, or looking for the same thing they were seeking).  For example, one of Fernando Cortez's translators was [Gerónimo de Aguilar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ger%C3%B3nimo_de_Aguilar), shipwrecked on the Yucatán penninsula (then thought to be an island) in 1511 and rescued in 1519.

And Cortez himself, after scuttling his ships in August 1519, was followed by another Spanish expedition that landed in April 1520 (with orders to arrest him for mutiny, dead or alive...)

So some factors that would make the scenario more realistic would be:

- The party going off to found a settlement and escape persecution or wickedness, not bring back treasure
- Blown off course due to bad weather or poor navigation, finding an island where none had been found before
- Reasons why the home country wouldn be looking for them
- As you mentioned in the question, away from established trade routes

Also, your question says "isolated" but not "uninhabited". Perhaps the island has existing inhabitants, who have been contacted but were warlike and ininterested in trade, but the new group is able to conquer or otherwise assimilate with them.

Answer (score 2):

Now, as we are necroposting, I have another idea. It's cold. Very cold.

## Arctic islands

- [Novaya Zemlya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Novaya_Zemlya) is a larger group of two major islands, Wikipedia in other language told me, they were explored in 11th and 16th centuries, there were expeditions in the end of 1500s, but the next ones were in 1821. So, drop off there in 1600 and you have two centuries when only some local hunters might visit you.
- [Saint Peter Islands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint_Peter_Islands) were discovered in 1736, anytime before it you are fine. The island are on the present-day Northern Sea Route, but this does not matter much in 15th century.
- [Sengeisky](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sengeiski) is said to be one of the hard-reachable islands in the Barents sea. It has no inhabitants as of today, it probably never had some. There is quite some fish, birds and further survuvalistic resources there. The only visit you risk, is from some locals, but I am not sure.

## Antarctica islands

- [South Orkney Islands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_Orkney_Islands) were discovered in 1821.
- [South Shetland Island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_Shetland_Islands) were discovered in 1819.
- [Balleny Islands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balleny_Islands) were discovered in 1839

In most of them, humans have not visited them for decades since. But, basically, arriving there in 16th century you do nothing wrong. Except, well, arriving *there*.

Comment: The rest of those survivors life would be quite short. But no-one will find them alive that's guaranteed. So, technically it's a correct answer.

Comment: Well, they could have built igloos, brought with them some generators and fuel, or build a boat and try to reach civilisation. But yeah, if unprepared and in cold season it looks pretty grim.

Answer (score 2):

Today..

North Sentinel Island, India is home to the Sentinelese, an indigenous people with no contact with the outside world. The Sentinelese are violently hostile to visitors and may attack with spears, bows, and arrows.

Few years ago a missionary tried to go to teach them about their god and got a spear for their trouble, so they're effectively cut off from the rest of the world and undisturbed.

Of course, for your story, you might need the Sentinelese to have died out so they don't kill your survivors (may be one of the shishkabobbed missionaries gave them a nice cold before expiring), only, the rest of the world doesn't know they've died out, so are still leaving them alone.